# Is it correct to use alignas(16) for an array[8] of m128?

Tags: c++, vectorization, memory-alignment, alignas

This is the code I usually write:

```
alignas(16) __m128 myBuffer[8];
```

But maybe (since the object-array is 128*8 bit = 128 byte) I should write:

```
alignas(128) __m128 myBuffer[8];
```

Or, "since the first 16 byte are aligned" in the first example, the rest will be automatically aligned in memory?

Comment: Why do you think `alignas()` is even needed with `__m128`?

Comment: With this question and your question in a comment in mind, I wonder what you think alignment means, and if maybe that's the cause for this confusion.

Comment: @harold put stuff in block that snap the value indicated by the function? sort of :)

Answer (score 2):

128-bit SIMD data types must be aligned on 16 bytes. The compiler already knows that, so it's not needed to align `__m128` manually. See for example, [MSVC docs on `__m128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/m128?view=msvc-160):

> Variables of type `__m128` are automatically aligned on 16-byte boundaries.

Also, arrays are contiguous. Each array element is naturally aligned the same as the first one. There's no need to multiply the alignment for arrays.

So you need not bother with `alignas` at all:

```
__m128 myBuffer[8];
```

This will just work.

Comment: so is it correct to use `alignas(4) std::array<float, 4097> mSamples`?

Comment: @markzzz `float` is in most cases already naturally aligned on 4 bytes, so `alignas(4)` here would make no difference. If you want to perform SIMD operations over this array, then you should use `alignas(16)` (or 32 when targeting AVX2 or later).

Comment: thats the question: why alignas(16) will differs from alignas(4) if they are consecutive?

Answer (score 1):

> is correct to use alignas(16) for an array[8] of m128?

It's not technically wrong, but according to documentation `__m128` is aligned to 16 bytes, so it's unnecessary to use `alignas`.

> But maybe ... I should write: `alignas(128)`

If your goal is to align to 128 bytes, then you can achieve it like that.

> Or "since the first 16 byte are aligned" in the first example, the rest will be automatically aligned in memory?

This question confuses me. If the integer is aligned, then the first byte is aligned. Rest of the bytes are offset from the first byte. In case the size is larger than alignment, some of the subsequent bytes would be aligned at offsets equal to the alignment.

---

Note that there is no `__m128` in standard C++.